# for each to get 3D array

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

Needed output to my previous post about declaration of 3d array, [getting error while 3D array declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971950/getting-error-while-3d-array-declare) .
I want to get the output of all first elements first, second elements second and so on with for each.
but currently I am getting the dimension wise. Can someone help me please to find the right approach? Here is my sample code:

```
Integer[][][] _3D = new Integer[][][]{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{2,4,5}},{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{2,4,5}}}; // it should be like this.


for (Integer[][] d3 : _3D) {
    for (Integer[] d2 : d3) {
        for (Integer d : d2) {
            System.out.print(d+"\t");  
                          // Expecting 1,4,7,2,1,4,7,2,2,5,8,4,2,5,8,4,3,6,9,5,3,6,9,5
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect the described output? You're iterating over all elements of your three dimensional array, so why do you think only the first elements get printed?

Comment: This would output the numbers in the order they are in the array declaration.

Comment: Are you sure all your sub-sub arrays will do the same length ?

Comment: @isnot2bad, I am looking for something like all row wise in 2D. so here I want to get the first element in array and second element in continues to first one end. I am get more dimensions also, that's why I am looking for each.

Comment: -1. Downvoting & voting to close, for lack of basic understanding/ or effort from the OP to use or understand his own loops.

Comment: How do you define row-wise in three dimensions? Defining your array as `_3D[x][y][z]` you're iterating first over `z`, then over `y`, then over `x`. What order do you want?

Answer (score 3):

In case you're sure your innermost array always has a length of three, you can do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (Integer[][] d3 : _3D) {
        for (Integer[] d2 : d3) {
            System.out.print(d2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Btw.: Why do you use an `Integer[][][]` instead of `int[][][]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all index 0, then all index 1, etc, you can't use a foreach, which iterates over elements of a single array.

Instead, try this:

```
for (Integer[][] d3 : _3D) 
    for (int i = 0; i < d3[0].length; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < d3.length; j++) 
            System.out.print(d3[j][i]+"\t");
```

Note the "inverted" nesting of the two inner loops.

Comment: Logical solution. The problem is that he can have more dimensions

Comment: @OlivierH I confess I didn't thoroughly read the question, but the title and code both say "3D". If it is arbitrary depth, a recursive solution is called for. Left to the reader :)

Comment: It is not quite what he wanted. The result is not 1,4,7,2,1,4,7,2... but 1,4,7,2,2,5,8,4...

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this code:

```
     Integer[][][] _3D = new Integer[][][]{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{2,4,5}},{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{2,4,5}}}; // it should be like this.


    //Expecting 1,4,7,2,1,4,7,2,2,5,8,4,2,5,8,4,3,6,9,5,3,6,9,5

    //Assume length are equal
    int length = _3D[0][0].length;

    for(int currColumn = 0; currColumn<length; currColumn++)
    {
        for (Integer[][] d3 : _3D) {

            for(int i =0; i<d3.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(d3[i][currColumn] +",");
            }

        }
    }
```

//Expecting 1,4,7,2,1,4,7,2,2,5,8,4,2,5,8,4,3,6,9,5,3,6,9,5

Output in Console:

```
        1,4,7,2,1,4,7,2,2,5,8,4,2,5,8,4,3,6,9,5,3,6,9,5,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for(int i=0;i<_3D[0][0].length;i++){
        for(int[][]_2D : _3D){
            for(int[] _1D : _2D){
                System.out.print(_1D[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("*****");
        }
    }
```